# Faster alternative to Series.add function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add two pandas Series together. The first Series is very large and has a MultiIndex. The index of the second series is a small subset of the index of the first.

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((1000,5000)),dtype=int).stack()
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns = ['total'])
    df2 = pd.concat([df1.iloc[50:55],df1.iloc[2000:2005]])  # df2 is tiny subset of df1
```

Using the regular Series.add function takes about 9 seconds the first time, and 2 seconds on subsequent tries (maybe because pandas optimizes how the df is stored in memory?).

```
    starttime = time.time()
    df1.total.add(df2.total,fill_value=0).sum()
    print "Method 1 took %f seconds" % (time.time() - starttime)
```

Manually iterating over rows takes about 2/3 as long as Series.add the first time, and about 1/100 as long as Series.add on subsequent tries.

```
    starttime = time.time()
    result = df1.total.copy()
    for row_index, row in df2.iterrows():
        result[row_index] += row
    print "Method 2 took %f seconds" % (time.time() - starttime)
```

The speed difference is particularly noticeable when (as here) the Index is a MultiIndex.

Why does Series.add not work well here? Any suggestions for speeding this up? Is there a more efficient alternative to iterating over each element of the Series?

Also, how do I sort or structure the data frame to improve the performance of either method? The second time either of these methods is run is appreciably faster. How do I get this performance on the first time? Sorting using sort_index helps only marginally.

Comment: The reason things are faster the 2nd time around is that the index hash table is calculated when needed then cached (this is what makes lookups of elements fast). What you are doing here is reindexing a much smaller series to the bigger series, which is why it takes time, but is uncessary; @HYRY solution below is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need for loop:

```
df1.total[df2.index] += df2.total
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks HYRY, and also Andy for the more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

As HYRY answers, the more efficient thing to do in this situation is to only look at the small subset of df2's index. You can do this, with the slightly more robust [add](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) function (which can fill NaNs):

```
df1.total[df2.index] = (df1.total[df2.index]).add(df2.total, fill_value=0)
```

*Although the syntax here is not very dry...*

To compare some timeit information, we can see that add isn't drastically slower, and both are an enormous improvement on your naive for loop:

```
In [11]: %%timeit
result = df1.total.copy()
for row_index, row in df2.iterrows():
    result[row_index] += row
100 loops, best of 3: 17.9 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit df1.total[df2.index] = (df1.total[df2.index]).add(df2.total, fill_value=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 325 µs per loop

In [13]: %timeit df1.total[df2.index] += df2.total
1000 loops, best of 3: 283 µs per loop
```

It's an interesting question (and I may fill this in later) to what relative size this will be faster with, but certainly in this extreme case there is a huge win...

#### The thing to take away from this:

If you are writing a for loop (in python) to speed something up, you're doing it wrong! :)

Comment: Thanks! The loop still beats the naive np.add, but adding on just a slice beats both hands down.

Answer (score 1):

I think your second might be faster in this specific case because you're iterating through the smaller dataset (small amount of work) and then accessing only a handful of components of the larger dataset (an efficient operation thanks to pandas developers).

However, with the `.add` method, pandas has to look look at the entirety of both indices.

If `df1` and `df2` are the same length, your first method takes 54 ms, but the second method takes >2 minutes (on my machine, obviously, YMMV).